# ASP textbox.text adding "," to my returned values

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I try to extract the value of an asp textbox, the returned value always have an "," (a comma) added to the value. For example, if I write "hello world" in this textbox, the returned value in the code behind is "hello world,". I don't know why asp textboxes behave in this way, it is normal?

My ASP button:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="streetNum" runat="server" style="float: left; width: 80px; margin-right: 12px" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

My code behind:

```
    public void bindData2()
    {
        string sss2 = streetNum.Text; //here the value obtained always have an "," extra at the final
    }
```

--Updated to show this image: The text entered in the asp textbox was "111", but the returned value is "111,"

[image]

Comment: You've got something else going on here - what you've posted will not result in an extra comma.

Comment: No, it's definitely not normal and doesn't behave like this by default. There's something else in effect, but we can't tell by this code snippet...

Comment: @JoeEnos trust me, as simple as looks, this thing is getting me crazy. Even if I extract the value of the textbox empty, returns an ","

Comment: `TextBox` doesn't have any special behavior. It is a server side element that when it will be rendered in the client will be appeared as a usal input html element. As for the `Text` property is the value you insert into the `input` or you `bind` as you have already done server side. In no way you get an extra ",", unless you have stated this explicitly.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm asking for help and maybe someboby had the same issue in the past.

Comment: You have two elements with the name `streetNum` in your source. Find the second one and rename it.

Comment: You need to show the rest of the code. As others have said, what you've shown here will not cause the described behavior.

Comment: @StarPilot Visual Studio doesn't reflect that I have a object with duplicated name, but I will take your advice and I will find thoroughly in all the document, is just a form with 11 elements, tough.

Comment: Write a new sample program with a single `asp:TextBox` control and see if you can replicate the behavior.  My bet is you cannot, but this exercise will hopefully lead you to see the solution in your existing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the situation in this way:

First, I replaced the asp textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="streetNumber" title="Street number" runat="server" style="float: left; width: 80px; margin-right: 12px" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

with a regular textbox running at server:

```
<input type="text" title="Street Number" id="streetNumber" style="float: left; width: 80px; margin-right: 12px" runat="server" />
```

and, in the code behind, I replaced:

```
public void bindData2(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string sss2 = streetNumber.Text;
}
```

with:

```
public void bindData2(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string sss2 = streetNumber.Value;
}
```

I really don't see a mayor difference, but works.